# Get a column value based on the certain number of values of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My dataframe `df` is:

```
data = {'Election Year':['2000', '2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005'],
    'Votes':[50, 100, 70, 26, 180, 100, 120, 46, 80, 129, 46, 95, 60, 23, 95, 16, 65, 35], 
    'Party': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Region': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c','a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    
    Election Year   Votes   Party   Region
  0   2000           50      A       a
  1   2000           100     B       a
  2   2000           70      C       a
  3   2000           26      A       b
  4   2000           180     B       b
  5   2000           100     C       b 
  6   2000           120     A       c
  7   2000           46      B       c
  8   2000           80      C       c
  9   2005           129     A       a
  10  2005           46      B       a
  11  2005           95      C       a
  12  2005           60      A       b
  13  2005           23      B       b
  14  2005           95      C       b
  15  2005           16      A       c
  16  2005           65      B       c
  17  2005           35      C       c
```

I want to get the regions in which minimum two parties got more than 50 votes in every election?. So the desired output is:

```
 Region
  a
  b
```

These are two regions in which miinimum two parties got 50 votes every year.

I tried to sort the "Election Year" and "Votes" and then  groupby on election year and Region to then see if top three of each region is getting more than 50 votes. But it is giving a different result.

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['Election Year','Votes'], ascending=(True,False))
top_3 = df1.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region']).head(3).reset_index()
```

How can I fix this to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Election Year':['2000', '2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005'],
    'Votes':[50, 100, 70, 26, 180, 100, 120, 46, 80, 129, 46, 95, 60, 23, 95, 16, 65, 35], 
    'Party': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Region': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c','a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df.where(df.Votes >= 50).groupby(['Election Year','Region']).count()
x[x.Party >= 2].reset_index().groupby('Region').count()
x = x[x.Party >= 2].reset_index().groupby('Region').count()
x[x['Election Year'] >= 2].index.values
```

This will give you:

```
array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In one column, some values have string inside the parenthesis at the end of those column string. But I want to remove only those parenthesis having cerrtain string. e.g. I want to keep "ka (A)", but remove (B) from "ka (B)". How to do this specific triming?

Comment: @Dpk I don't think I get your question. I guess it will be better to ask a new question and you supply there sample of the data and expected output. But I guess you could use `apply`

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion. I will ask a new question. Actually, users with lower reputations are not allowed to ask question frequently. But thanks for your suggestion to minimize the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try withh `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
>>> ( df.query('Votes >= 50')
        .groupby(['Region', 'Year'])
        .size().unstack('Year')
        .gt(1).all(1).loc[lambda x:x].index )

Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='Region')
```